# DJI RS 2: Calculate Attitude from Joint Angles

Tags: python, numpy, robotics

At the moment I'm working on the DJI Ronin RS 2 gimbal. The configuration is shown in the image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwrme.png) There is a camera mounted on the gimbal. The red arrows mark the axes of the gimbal. The joint angles alpha, beta and gamma are measured and therefore known. The green coordinate system is the fixed reference system.

So much for the setup. Now to the complicated part: How can I combine the angles alpha, beta and gamma to calculate one yaw angle (around green z-axis), one roll angle (around green x-axis) and one pitch angle (around green z-axis) in the reference system, to let me know where the camera is pointing to?

I know that I could also get the attitude-information directly from the gimbal by sending another "obtain"-command. However, I do need the joint angles and the attitude angles. Therefore I thought it would be easier to calculate the attitude angles from the joint angles.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you.

So far, I set up different rotation matrices (basic rotations around x-, y-, z-axis combined by multiplication) and tried to calculate the attitude with the following formulas:

```
def Rx(a):
    # Transformation to radiant
    a = np.radians(a)
    Rx = [[1, 0, 0],
          [0, np.cos(a), np.sin(a)],
          [0, -np.sin(a), np.cos(a)]]
    Rx = np.round(Rx, decimals = 3)
    return Rx

def Ry(a):
    # Transformation to radiant
    a = np.radians(a)
    Ry = [[np.cos(a), 0, -np.sin(a)],
          [0, 1, 0],
          [np.sin(a), 0, np.cos(a)]]
    Ry = np.round(Ry, decimals = 3)
    return Ry

def Rz(a):
    # Transformation to radiant
    a = np.radians(a)
    Rz = [[np.cos(a), np.sin(a), 0],
          [-np.sin(a), np.cos(a), 0],
          [0, 0, 1]]
    Rz = np.round(Rz, decimals = 3)
    return Rz

# Rotation around z-axis
R10 = Rz(alpha)

# Rotation around y-axis
R21 = Ry(55)

# Rotation around x-axis
R32 = Rx(beta)

# Rotation around y-axis
R43 = Ry(gamma)

R20 = np.matmul(R21, R10)
R30 = np.matmul(R32, R20)
R = np.matmul (R43, R30)

pitch = -np.arcsin(R[2,0])
roll = np.arctan2(R[2,1]/np.cos(pitch), R[2,2]/np.cos(pitch))
yaw = np.arctan2(R[1,0]/np.cos(pitch), R[0,0]/np.cos(pitch))`
```

Unfortunately, this hasn't led to the right result yet. I guess that these formulas only apply to rotation around x-, y-, and z-axis in a certain order. This gimbal uses another rotation axis due to the joint in the middle.

Comment: How do you define pitch, roll and yaw? I would expect pitch to be about the X axis, roll about the Y and yaw about the Z, but you don't seem to do this. So can you specify what you're using? Also, you mention alpha, beta and gamma but don't actually use them in your code. I assume you used them to calculate R. How?